# rake:db migrate isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rake-task

I'm trying to run a migration on my Rails app, by using rake:db migrate --trace and I get the following output:

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
```

It then doesn't do anything after this. If I Ctrl + C I get some errors, but I'm not sure I understand them. Is there any way I can step through and debug the migration process so I can see when it hits the problem migration?

Comment: It'd also be helpful to find out if rake is actually invoking the application or if its not even getting that far

Comment: Does your migration successfully created? Did you check the timestamp or file creation date?

Comment: Do you mean `rake db:migrate`? In your title and question you have `rake:db migrate`.

Answer (score 1):

its (**space** between rake and db).

```
rake db:migrate
```

try for a overview of rake db tasks:

```
rake -T db
```

Comment: Yeah sorry, typo on my part. I wasn't trying rake:db migrate ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace
```

Comment: Same output as rake db:migrate --trace

Answer (score 0):

I realized the reason this was not firing was it was initializing a sleep command waiting on something that wouldn't be initialized via rake (the app had to be running). So, rake was not the culprit this time!